# SystemStackError caught locally but causes production server to stop

Tags: ruby, xml, xslt, amazon-web-services, nokogiri

I am working on a Ruby project where I need to transform a raw xml document using an xsl stylesheet from my user.

Recently I realized that some of the stylesheets from my user have infinite loops, causing my app to crash so I added some error handling to prevent such event from happening.

```
 rescue SystemStackError, NoMemoryError  => e
   puts "error caught #{e.inspect}"
```

I was able to successfully rescue this error when I was running the app locally but when I deployed it to my aws instance, **using the same stylesheet**, this error was only caught for small files (for example, a ~200KB xml).

With larger xmls (say 4MB) the app seems to be stuck (it will never finish the current task nor move on to the next).

I thought I did not have enough memory on my aws instance but even after changing it from t2.micro to t2.large (which has the same amount of memory as my local machine) my app would still get stuck for no reason.

I have compared all the gems in both my local machine and my aws instance and they all have the same versions. I am using Nokorigi (1.6.7).

Can someone please give me some suggestions as to where I should look? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

PS: I should mention that, out of desperation, I even added statements like this

```
rescue Exception => e
  #log exception here
```

at the end of all my other error handling code, hoping to catch a glimpse of the problem... but alas the ghost remains anonymous and deadly. :(

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause for the issue and thought I'd share what I learned:

- even when I was rescuing the **SystemStackError**, the garbage collector wasn't cleaning up the memory and the memory leak eventually led to the production instance stopping to work
- the same memory leak was happening locally as well but because my local machine had a lot more memory than our production instance, it took much much longer to crash (so it *appeared* to be working properly locally in the beginning)
- the "fix" was to use both Nokogiri and [Ruby-xslt](https://github.com/glejeune/ruby-xslt) gems - Nokogiri handles the majority of the xsl transformations beautifully but when it does fail the Ruby-xslt gem seems to handle the weird cases alright. So in my code I ended up trying to transform with Nokogiri first, and if it fails, when transform with xslt.

Hope this helps. :)